# How to get rid of &nbsp; in AA

Tags: html, excel, automation, whitespace, automationanywhere

I am reading data (combination of letters and numbers) from an excel sheet and put it into a text field in target application, where the input should yield a unique item from a database.

However there (sometimes) is a whitespace behind the data in the excel cell, which results in a "no data found" when this whitespace is entered into the search field in target application. The whitespace does not seem to be a space though, since i am unable to trim that whitespace AA-internally. I guess it is a `&nbsp;` (or some similar html special character).

edit: confirmed to be a `&nbsp;` by now.

Q: How can i get rid of such characters AA internally?

Tried: Neither (a) Trim, (b) Replace " " ->"", nor (c) Replace "`&nbsp;`"->"" work.

Workaround: I am currently checking for the length of the data provided: if its longer than 10 chars i only take the leftmost 10 chars. This works here, since its a business rule for the data i am working with, but i am still interested in an original solution, since there may be upcoming cases, where no business rule will help me out.

AA Version: 11.3.1

Thankful for input...

Comment: Can you copy the cell and paste it here in a separate line? or comment?

Comment: will post two cells in the following comments:

Comment: *need more chars*PA0KKS2302

Comment: It seems Stack Overflow ignores these chars, can you paste the cell into this website and click on show me the characters https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Comment: Thanks for that page. Will be pretty useful from time to time :)
U+A0 is the character, which is indeed a &nbsp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since it's non-breaking spaces character, you can replace it using Regex in replace command.

**Find:** `\u00a0`
**Options:** Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of it using Replace Command with RegEx ticked:

[^a-z A-Z 0-9]

Comment: This can cause a problem if the data contains email or any special characters like @ or dot.

Comment: in my case it can only be numbers and letters. But yes, for other cases this needs to be kept in mind. Thanks